# Use Autolayout and CGAffineTransform

Tags: ios, swift, rotation, autolayout, transform

I have a problem with using Autolayout and Rotation. 
In my application I got a wheel on which there are several views which need to be rotated to fit in the circle (which is pan able, scrollable).

The dark square is the background of the `MenuView` which contains a `UILabel`, two `UIImageViews` and three `UIButtons`. All held in place by constraints, specified in a `XIB` file.

Everything works fine until I rotate the view to something other than 0, 90, 180, 270, ... where all the contents of the `MenuView` get an x offset.

I don't know how to get rid of this offset. Maybe it has something to do with `translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints` but I couldn't figure out the right use of it on the right views. Hopefully someone can help me with this problem.

**Code**

```
//Menu View Holder
let menuViewHolder = UIView(frame: self.bounds)
self.addSubview(menuViewHolder)
viewHolders.append(menuViewHolder)

//Menu View
let menuView = self.addView(MenuView.self, fromNib: "MenuView")
menuView.colorSet = UIColorSet.getDefaultSet()
menuView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = true
menuViewHolder.addSubview(menuView)
views.append(menuView)

//Frame
let screenWidth:CGFloat = 320.0
let width:CGFloat = screenWidth
let height:CGFloat = 300.0
menuView.frame = CGRect(x: (self.bounds.width-width)/2.0, y: 0.0, width: width, height: height)

//Rotation
let angle = CGFloat(menuViewIndex)*CGFloat(viewAngle);
//menuViewHolder.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(angle + CGFloat(M_PI/2.0))
menuViewHolder.layer.transform = CATransform3DMakeRotation(angle + CGFloat(M_PI/2.0), 0, 0, 1)
```

**Visual**

[image: WheelView in 0, 30, 60, 90 degrees rotation]

Comment: I am unsure what exactly you would expect to happen, what you should be displayed where? In general the transforms are *completely* ignored by autolayout, they operate on a completely different level.

Comment: Well since all the labels and buttons inside `MenuView` are set to stay in its bounds I would assume that they stay in their bounds after rotating, too. As you can see in the image that's not the case for 30° and 60°

Comment: **No**. you are transforming the CoreGraphics `layer`, that has little to do with UIKit or layout - it does not care about it at all.

Comment: But it some how does. Or where else should this offset come from? And why should it be working then for 90° too. I am not touching the labels and buttons frame or position. And as you can see the frame of the view which contains all those is perfectly fine.

Comment: Just for demonstration's sake (because I have to go now): if you have two equally sized squares lying on top of each other and you rotate the top one its corners will always lay outside the area of the lower square unless you rotate around 90, 180 or 270 degree.

Comment: Yes, that's true. But I don't get what you trying to explain to me with this thesis?

Answer (score 1):

Allright, I kinda fixed it.

I set up all frames, rotation and adding subviews in `viewDidLoad` of my `UIViewController`.
When I rotate in `viewDidAppear` everything works just fine. It is a bit odd that setting frames and rotating in code one after another will affect each other. While waiting for the view to fully setup (done through `viewDidAppear`) fixes those problems.